# R - How to avoid loop in list of files

Tags: r, for-loop

My current learning goal in R is to avoid `for` loops. I very often have to list the files in a directory (or loops through directories) to perform diverse operations on those files.

One example of my task is the following: I have to invoke a system application called `cdo` to merge two files. The syntax of this command is, let's say: `cdo merge input_file1 input_file2 output_file`.

My current R code looks like this:

```
# set lists of files
u.files <- c("uas_Amon_ACCESS1-3.nc", "uas_Amon_CMCC-CESM.nc", "uas_Amon_CMCC-CESM.nc")
v.files <- c("vas_Amon_ACCESS1-3.nc", "vas_Amon_CMCC-CESM.nc", "vas_Amon_CMCC-CESM.nc")

for (i in 1:length(u.files)) {

  # set input file 1 to use on cdo
  input1 <- paste(u.files[i], sep='')

  # set input file 2 to use on cdo
  input2 <- paste(v.files[i], sep='')

  # set output file to use on cdo
  output <- paste('output_', u.files[i], sep='') 

  # assemble the command string 
  comm <- paste('cdo merge', input1, input2, output, collapse='')

  # submit the command
  system(comm)

}
```

which works ok although does not look that good.

However, I often times hear people saying that `for` loops in R are slow and should be avoided as much as possible.

Is there any way to avoid the for loops and make the code more efficient/legible in cases like this?

Comment: Here, you only use R to run a system tool (i.e. cdo). From my point of view, it might be more efficient to directly use a shell script.

Comment: @Pascal, this code is actually an excerpt. In reality I have way more stuff going one inside the loop until it gets to this point. But all the other commands also involve indexing in the loop, so if I understand the logic behind the elimination of the loop I would be able to use it in my actual script.

Comment: I just signal you can simplify your R code by removing all unnessary system calls, by prepocessing. But of course, it is up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more R-idiomatic:

```
u.files <- c("uas_Amon_ACCESS1-3.nc", "uas_Amon_CMCC-CESM.nc", "uas_Amon_CMCC-CESM.nc")
v.files <- c("vas_Amon_ACCESS1-3.nc", "vas_Amon_CMCC-CESM.nc", "vas_Amon_CMCC-CESM.nc")
output <- paste('output_', u.files, sep='')
comm <- paste('cdo merge', u.files, v.files, output)
lapply(comm,system)
```

Remember that most functions are vectorized in R, so you don't have to call `paste` for each iteration in the loop. At the end you obtain a vector of commands and execute one by one through `lapply` in the last line.